# Delete User input Python

Tags: python, input, delete-row, sys

If I have an easy code like this:

```
while 1:
    text = raw_input()
    print 'You have written "%s" text'% (text)
```

if I start the program and I write "hello" the Output is:

```
hello
You have written "hello" text
```

The first "hello" is my input (taken with raw_input but I could use sys.stdin.readline too)

How I can delete the first "hello" (my input) to have an output only like this:

```
You have written "hello" text
```

Comment: import curses; curses.noecho() (unix-based only)

Comment: that's not something you want to do usually; the user normally wants to see what he/she's entering. except for passwords. you  could have a look at [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass).

Comment: can i do without importing curses?

Comment: i need this for a chatting client

Comment: maybe: https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the CLI before printing your wanted line.

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

If it's a Unix system. On Windows it's `cls`.

Edit:
If you need this for a chat client you could save your user inputs in a list and clear the cli and print your user inputs list

```
userInputs = []
...
text = raw_input ()
userInputs.append (text)   
os.system ('clear')
for i in userInputs:
    print (i)
```

Comment: Also: `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`

Comment: Thanks, but with this code i delete all the text in the console and i don't want , i only want to delete user input

Comment: Hm... there is no simple way to prevent input is printed. You could cache the wanted output, clear the cli and print your cached output again with your new line and so on.

Comment: I need this becouse when I write on my client  ( http://pastebin.com/JB36Emx6 )and I enter the input and then recive the same input from the server but with the time ,the address ,and other information, I prefer to recive only from the server and not see my input in the console ... sorry for my english

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: thanks is a good solution

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you could mark it as accepted :)